# Why I get overwritten entry results with Hibernate and java?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have a pretty complex query to retrieve some data from the database. When running the query in console, it provides the correct results. When ran from java, the results are overwritten. for example,

from db:  (x, 1, 6) (x, 2, 7) (x, 5, 8) (y, 1, 4) (y, 7, 9)

from java:(x, 1, 6) (x, 1, 6) (x, 1, 6) (y, 1, 4) (y, 1, 4)

why would this happend? sketch of query here:

```
@Override
public List<TestDTO> fetchExternalLecturersFromPTeams() {
Query nativeQuery = em.createNativeQuery(SELECT DISTINCT
    l.id AS lecturerId,
    l.last_name AS lecturerLastName,
    l.first_name AS lecturerFirstName,
    s.short_name AS course,
    t.exam_date AS examDate,
    st.id AS studentId,
    st.first_name AS studentFirstName,
    st.last_name AS studentLastName,
    i.registration_date AS registrationDate,
    FALSE AS firstSupervisor,
    FALSE AS secondSupervisor,
    FALSE AS thesisAdvisor,
    TRUE AS examiner
FROM team t
JOIN team_to_person tp ON t.id = tp.team_id
JOIN persons l ON tp.person_id = l.id
JOIN team_to_student ts ON t.id = ts.team_id
JOIN persons st ON ts.person_id = st.id
JOIN studies std ON st.id = std.person_id
JOIN course_exam_dates ced ON t.course_exam_date_id = ced.id
JOIN course_version cv ON ced.course_version_id = cv.id
JOIN course c ON cv.course_id = c.id
JOIN person_contract pc ON pc.person_id = l.id
JOIN registrations r ON std.id = r.study_id
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) AS max_id, study_id
    FROM registrations
    GROUP BY study_id
) latest_reg ON std.id = latest_reg.study_id
JOIN registrations latest_r ON latest_r.id = latest_reg.max_id
WHERE std.course_id = c.id
ORDER BY examDate DESC, TestDTO.class);

List<TestDTO> list = new ArrayList<>(nativeQuery.getResultList());
```

Comment: How should we say it without seeing your code?

Comment: @Jens, I supposed that the query is enough, I added now the few lines of code of this method. Literally, the elements in the list are already overwritten. The DTO  class is just a class with primitive fields and a Date field

Comment: Shot in the dark: did you change data in the console or in java code? Might be un-commited changes in one of the connections.

Comment: The query returns 13 columns, the `TestDTO` seems to have only 3 fields. What is the mapping from the columns to the fields?

Comment: the DTO object has exactly the 13 same fields named as the ones returned by this query. Fortunately, I solved the problem, I removed the .class parameter when creating the native query, and then I map manually the fields to the dto objects. I still don't understand why the problem occured, but at least i found a solution.